# British India records for Native Indians and Pakistanis

Tags: birth-records, marriage-records, death-records, india, family-register

Where can I find **birth**, **death**, and **marriage records**, as well as the **register of persons** for **British India** for **Native Indians and Pakistanis**? As far as I know, the people that I am researching are all **Muslims** by Religion.

I have checked the records for British India on Ancestry and Findmypast, but they are mainly for  **Anglo-Indian, British, European Christians and native converts**. They **do not** hold births, marriages and deaths for Hindus, Muslims, etc.

I am researching the record below:

Records of the British in India (also called The British Raj, Crown rule in India or Direct rule in India), 1858 -1947 (89 years)

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than two like you have here. I think you should [edit] this question to make it about one or other of Aden and India, and then create a new question for the other.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you for the guidance. I will do what you said.